# F# TypeProviders, how to Change Database?

Tags: f#, type-providers

Am using F# TypeProviders for processing SQL data from two different servers but many databases. It is going fine except for the speed now which is becoming very slow as I add more files. As at now each file has its own connection string. I was thinking of extracting the connection string and Type provider to an external project with the ability to pass database as an argument. Trying to achieve this, I attempt the following, following the 3rd answer from the following link [F# Type Provider, create with string variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23598250/f-data-type-provider-create-with-string-variable):

```
open System.Configuration
open System.Data.SqlClient
open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders
open System.Data.SqlClient

let con = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Item("conDebug")
let setDB dbName =
    let cn = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(con)
    cn.InitialCatalog <- dbName
    cn.ConnectionString

[<Literal>]
let conStr = setDB "AnotherDB"

type selectedDb = SqlDataConnection<conStr>
```

but kept on getting the error:
***This is not a valid constant expression***
Is it also possible to use the `ChangeDatabase` member in the `SqlDataConnection`?

**Update:**
The answer suggested won't solve my problem in this case. Below is what is similar to what am doing for different tables from two different servers:

```
[<Literal>]
let sourceConStr = @"sourceCon"

type sourceDB = SqlDataConnection<sourceConStr>

type person =
    { Id : string
      birthDate : Nullable<DateTime>
      firstName : string
      lastName : string
      dateCreated : DateTime }

type processPeople()
    member this.makePerson(oldPerson: source.ServiceTypes.Person) =
        { Id = oldPerson.oldId
        ......some other processing of old data
        }

     member this.transferPeople conStr =
        use source = sourceDB.GetDataContext()
        use sw = File.AppendText("./ImportLog.txt")
        use targetCon = new SqlConnection(conStr)
        targetCon.Open()
        let query = "insert query"            

        let insert person =
            try
                use cmd = new SqlCommand(query, targetCon)
                ....setting parameters stuff......                
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() |> ignore
            with sx -> sw.WriteLine(sx.Message)
        source.source.ServiceTypes.Person
        |> Seq.map this.makePerson
        |> Seq.filter (fun p -> p.Id <> null && p.birthDate.HasValue )
        |> Seq.iter insert
        printfn "Done"
```

Now I need to do this for every table i.e class per table and as the files grow compilation and for intellisense to start takes so long.

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107676/f-type-provider-for-sql-in-a-class

Comment: The code in your question update over complicates things by using separate non-typed connection for inserts; doing instead`use source = sourceDB.GetDataContext(conStr)` and performing inserts from LINQ would eliminate roughly 70% of your code. Or, if you do not like LINQ for some reasons and you are in Sql2012 or higher realm, switch to excellent [SqlClient](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data.SqlClient/) type provider and stay in ADO world.

Comment: The type Person will ensure types are exactly the same. I did checked SqlClient but couldn't use it as running on a lower version. Also some of the data is very old and difficult to work with and thus very much limited. Also the data is sent to a different server and `conStr` is only for the destination. If you observe well, you'll notice that `use source = sourceDB.GetDataContext` is using the same source as the make. The source and destination also, most of the time are different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a fundamental flaw in the approach you're trying to take. You want getting a connection string from your application configuration **at run time** and offer `SqlDataConnection` type provider to make its magic with underlying database.

But this type provider simply cannot do anything at run time stage of workflow as its job has to be already completed **at compile time** on some **known at compile time** database.

Then, you may ask, what is the point of using type provider if we want to make our code, after being compiled once, being able to work with database(s) configurable in run-time?

Right, but we do expect results of type provider work being applicable to **structurally the same** databases, do we?

So, the way out is offering type provider to do its job upon a database `compileTimeDB` with **literally** known at compile time connection string `compileTimeCC`, and consider all goodies we getting (type checks, Intellisense,...) **parameterized** upon a connection string. This connection string parameter value `runTimeCC` can be set at run time in any desirable way as long as it points to a database `runTimeDB` with the same schema as `compileTimeDB` .

Illustrating this fundamental principle with a bit of code below:

```
[<Literal>]
let compileTimeCC = @"Data Source=(localdb)\ProjectsV12;Initial Catalog=compileTimeDB;Integrated Security=True;"
.....
type MySqlConnection = SqlDataConnection<ConnectionString = compileTimeCC>
// Type provider is happy, let it help us writing our DB-related code
.....
let db = MySqlConnection.GetDataContext(runTimeCC)
// at run time db will be a runTimeDB set by connection string runTimeCC that can be any
// as long as runTimeDB and compileTimeDB has same schema
.....
```

**UPDATE** as question author made his problem context clearer I may suggest more specific recommendation upon approaching this with the given TP. As SO answers should be reasonably concise let's limit consideration by two legacy `Person` types `OldPersonT1` and `OldPersonT2` as data sources and one contemporary `ModernPerson` type as destination. I'm talking **types** here, it can be as many as you want **instances** of such around your DB farm.

Now, let's create a single DB at your `localdb` named `CompileTypeDB` and run Sql scripts for creating tables corresponding to `OldPersonT1`,`OldPersonT2`, and `ModernPerson`(it's one time exercise and no real data moving will be involved). This will be a single source of type info for `SqlDataConnection` TP.

Having this ready, let get back to the code:

```
type CTSqlConn = SqlDataConnection<ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\Projectsv12;Initial Catalog=myCompileTimeDB;Integrated Security=True">

type OldPersonT1 = CTSqlConn.ServiceTypes.OldPersonT1 // just for brevity
type OldPersonT2 = CTSqlConn.ServiceTypes.OldPersonT2
type ModernPerson = CTSqlConn.ServiceTypes.ModernPerson
```

Then, augment each of legacy types with the following static member (given below for `OldPersonT1` only for brevity):

```
type CTSqlConn.ServiceTypes.OldPersonT1 with
    static member MakeModernPersons(rtConn: string) =
        let projection (old: OldPersonT1) =
            // Just a direct copy, but you may be very flexible in spreading verification
            // logic between query, projection, and even makeModernPersons function
            // that will be processing IQueryable<ModernPerson>
            let mp = ModernPerson()
                mp.Id <- old.Id
                mp.birthDate <- old.birthDate
                mp.firstName <- old.firstName 
                mp.lastName <- old.lastName 
                mp.dateCreated <- old.dateCreated
                mp 
        query {
            for oldPerson in (CTSqlConn.GetDataContext(rtConn)).OldPersonT1 do
            select (projection oldPerson)
        }
```

Now you can get hold on `IQueryable<ModernPerson>` from any data source of type `OldPersonT1` by merely evaluating

```
OldPersonT1.MakeModernPersons("real time connection string to any DB having OldPersonT1 table")
```

For this to work real time DB may be not identical to compile time DB, it just should contain everything that `OldPersonT1` has and depends upon.
Similarly would be true for `OldPersonT2` or any other variation type: by implementing `MakeModernPersons` once per variation type you get all data source instances covered.

Doing with data destination requires a single function with signature

```
let makeModernPersons destinationConnStr (source: IQueryable<ModernPerson>) =
...
```

that now covers all possible combinations of `Person` data sources and destinations just by manipulating values of two real-time connection strings.

Very rough cut, but the idea seems quite clear.

Comment: I know type providers up to that level, I was just thinking there could be a way to change the database or at least loading all schemas based on a connection so I don't have to repeat all these on each class.

Comment: And also making compilation and intellisense faster.

Comment: @zulq: Your comment kinda contradicts your statement :), all schemas (tables, SPs...) are loaded **exactly once at compile time** upon compiler processes `type X = SqlDataConnection<literal>`. You cannot get anything  more, or less, or different from `X`, just can use provided types with different instances of databases where generated types of `X` stay.

Comment: Kinda out of luck here for optimization I believe.

Comment: @zulq: Not really, you just need to regroup what you have a bit. See my update to the original question.

Comment: can you give an example of `<code your projection given both OldPersonT1 and ModernPerson types are available here>`.

Comment: @zulg: Sure, see the updated snippet within the answer